# UV Separation not sure where to weld

Tags: uv, uv-image-editor

So the uv layout was going really well until I hit the last parts of the sleeve...I'm not quite sure what to do since half of the circle belongs to one island and the other half belongs to the other island...I don't want to mess up the work I just did on all the others. How do I go about connecting these to one or the other?

[image]

I've been stuck on a lot of stuff before but this one is new. Please Help!

[image]

Comment: What is your desired result ? You can connect islands one to another with using *Stitch* tool by pressing V (you might want to select less islands so it not stitches everything).

Comment: Well, I'm trying to stitch the islands...the half circles off to the left aren't doing it. I need those two and the circle underneath the two rectangles on the left to be a part of the other islands. Like I said, half of the three trouble islands are connected to one main island, while the other half is connected to another. I can't figure out how to separate them so I can sew them to the correct islands...

Comment: I'm continuing to mess with it and was able to get the circle attached after ripping a few verts....still can't figure out the half circles yet...

Comment: ok I'm just ripping verts until they separate and then welding them back together. It's probably too late for me, but if anyone knows a faster way to help someone else, that'd be great.

Comment: Several vertices from other islands become selected while selecting trouble islands because you have *Keep UV and Edit mode mesh selection in sync* on. Probably this is what you meant by "the other half connected to another".